# How to pass int value from one activity to another activity's Text View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to make simple converter app.
here is the image of what i want to create. There are actually three layout (Activities)
But actually those two are matters most. There might be unwanted code lines cus am not familiar with android developments. I tryed hard to do this. I think now am getting converted answer to int but still i dont knw how to display it on other view's Textview.

here is the image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3siMB02QAyJLW1Ec3lkbDBWUVE/edit?usp=sharing

here is my code. Appreciate any help!

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText text = null;
int enterValue = 0;



public void convert(View view) {

    RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.farenhite);
    RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.celcius);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String temporary = text.getText().toString();
    int check = Integer.parseInt(temporary);

    if (check == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    float inputValue = check;

    if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
        // celFinal = inputValue;

        convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (fahrenheitButton.isChecked()) {

        convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (celsiusButton.isChecked() && fahrenheitButton.isChecked()) {


        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected both!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    } 

    /*
     * make buttons true and false if (fahrenheitButton.isChecked()) {
     * fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false); celsiusButton.setChecked(true); }
     * else { fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
     * celsiusButton.setChecked(false); }
     */

}

// Converts to celsius
private double convertFahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {


    double temp = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);

    Intent myintent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("tempthing", temp);
    startActivity(myintent);
    return temp;

}

// Converts to fahrenheit
private double convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {


    double temp = ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
    Intent myintent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("tempthing", temp);
    startActivity(myintent);
    return temp;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this is the code of next view

public class ThirdActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if((intent.getExtras()!=null) && !intent.getExtras().isEmpty()){

        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        int intValue = myintent.getIntExtra("tempthing", 0);

        final TextView textViewTEST=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textViewTEST.setText(intValue);

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The reason:

In `SecondActivity` you put a `double` extra called "**tempthing**" to intent extras using `putExtra(String key, Double value)` method. If you will hold mouse over `putExtra` method you will see that it uses variant with `double` argument.

```
double temp = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
[...]
myintent.putExtra("tempthing", temp); <- puts double
```

But in your `ThirdActivity` you're asking for an `int` extra using  `getIntExtra` method.

```
int intValue = myintent.getIntExtra("tempthing", 0);
```

There is no `int` extra called "**tempthing**" inside - there is however a `double` extra with that key.

### Solution:

So either you will put the `int` value in `SecondActivity`:

```
myintent.putExtra("tempthing", (int)temp);
```

or get a `double` value in `ThirdActivity`:

```
double doubleValue = myintent.getDoubleExtra("tempthing", 0);
```

They just need to match. If you put `double` - read `double`. If you put `int` - read `int` :)

Comment: Thnx bro it works! bt still it shows 0.0 on text view not the converted answer. So i think my coverting methods are not working properly.

Comment: Oops sry about my previous comment! it works fine! 100% thnx alot bro! Really appreciate your help! Thanx again!

Comment: No problem :) if an answer helps you to resolve your problem you should accept it by clicking on the "tick" (checkmark) to the left. It indicates that the answer is right and will help other people to find that.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("INTEGER",value);   
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("your_key",value);   // your_key => tempthing
startActivity(intent);
```

and set value int ThirdActivity

```
final TextView textViewTEST=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 textViewTEST.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
```